# Increment version number in file via bash command

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a XML file that has a version number in the following format:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.4">
```

I want to find the last number in the version string (i.e. "4" in this example) and then increment it by one - replacing it in the file. Ideally using simple bash commands (AWK?).

Comment: So `1.2.3.9` should become `1.2.4.0` ?

Comment: No, I just want to increment it continuously.

Comment: do you only want to bump the last number in the version string? but what if you want to bump the minor-version (`1.2.3.9` -> `1.3.0.0`)?

Comment: For minor upgrades I would do a manual build. For the patch builds, I've had them automated for my particular use case.

Answer (score 5):

You may use perl.

```
perl -i -pe 's/\b(\d+)(?=\D*$)/$1+1/e' file
```

or

```
perl -i -pe 's/\bVersion="[^"]*\K\b(\d+)(?=[^"]*")/$1+1/e' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo '<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.4">' | perl -pe 's/\b(\d+)(?=\D*$)/$1+1/e'
<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.5">
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to increment another number later in the file, and skips the version field altogether.

Comment: You the one said the last number. You didn't talk about the version. Check my update.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the last number for the version field, i.e. 1.2.3.4. I tried the second command but that removes the Version="1.2.3.4" and replaces it with 5"

Comment: forget to add `\K`, check now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is called version.xml, you can try the following:

```
CURRENT=$(awk -F'"' '{print $8}' version.xml)
NEXT=$(echo ${CURRENT}|awk -F. '{print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4+1}')
sed "s/Version.*/Version=\"${NEXT}\">/g" version.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk command that should work on non-gnu awk (BSD) versions as well:

```
s='<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.9">'

awk -F '[="]+' '{
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($(i-1) == " Version") {
           n = split($i, vers, ".");
           sub(/\.[0-9]+"/, "." vers[n]+1 "\"")
      }
} 1' <<< "$s"
```

**Output:**

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.10">
```

Answer (score 0):

I can try with awk [match and gsub functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

```
echo '<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.4">' |
awk '{
  match($0, /\.([0-9]+)([^0-9]*)$/, a); 
  gsub(/\.([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$/,"." a[1]+1 a[2]); 
  print;
}'
```

you get

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.5">
```

if input is, for example:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.99">
```

output is:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="Name" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.100">
```